# Why does this shell script not run?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm trying to run this script

```
echo "Buscando Instancias Del Servidor Corriendo Actualmente...."
processId=$(ps -fea | grep jboss | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs)
host=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'  | head -1)
echo "$processId"
echo "$host"
if [ -z "$processId"]
  then
  echo "hay instancias corriendo del servidor con Id proceso:  $processId"
else
  echo "No Hay Instancias Del Servidor Corriendo Actualmente"
fi
```

But I get this error:

> syntax error near unexpected token `fi`

Comment: You need a space before the `]`. Run your code through http://www.shellcheck.net .

Comment: Shame but get the same error

Comment: If you have an update to your question, edit the original question. Reading code in the comments is impossible.

Comment: If you fix that spacing error the rest looks ok. Update with the fixed code and the exact error message you get at that point. Also make sure this file doesn't have DOS line endings.

Comment: I think your message in if and else is swapped. :-/

Comment: You also have a space after the `fi` . Remove that and it should work.

Comment: @rahul, whitespace at the end of line is not a problem.

Comment: I could run your script successfully using `zsh`, `bash` and also `csh` on RHEL 5.9

Comment: @MichaelVega Does the script have a shebang? How are you running it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space before your closing brackt in your if statement like so:

```
echo "Buscando Instancias Del Servidor Corriendo Actualmente...."
processId=$(ps -fea | grep jboss | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs)
host=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'  | head -1)
echo "$processId"
echo "$host"
if [ -z "$processId" ]
  then
  echo "hay instancias corriendo del servidor con Id proceso:  $processId"
else
  echo "No Hay Instancias Del Servidor Corriendo Actualmente"
fi
```